# tomcat 6.0, how to set jsp source level to jdk 1.3 or jdk 1.4

Tags: tomcat

I am developing a web app on tomcat 6, the web app will be deployed on websphere which compile jsp at source level 1.3, but tomcat 6 can accept jdk 1.5 syntax

Comment: Java 1.3? `::shudder::` http://i.imgur.com/B6wXrl.png

Comment: Good god, why?  Is this because of WebSphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use Tomcat 4.1.40 from the archives:

http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-4/

The following link has a table which shows the tomcat/jdk relationship:

http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: however, the websphere can accept servlet and other java classes compiled with JDK 1.5